# Htmlunit for android - Javascript captcha

Tags: java, android, http, request, htmlunit

I need to use HtmlUnit in android, because I need the javascript loaded in the captcha request, and using native HTTPRequest is not possible.

example:

```
WebRequest request = new WebRequest (new URL (
                 "http://steamcommunity.com/id/bobcatchris/inventory#730"));
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError (false);
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout (10000);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

How can I do this in android?

I tried to use HtmlUnit in android without success.